# How can I declare an array with a variable, but without using malloc() in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

So I have to create a 2D array which is going to be used to print a histogram. I know that the array is going to be 52 elements wide, but the height of the array is going to be equal to `max + 1`, which will be different every time the function it is in gets called. Ideally, the line would accomplish the following function:

```
char histPlot[max+1][52] = "";
```

As I was writing my code, however, I learned that C, or at least my compiler, does not allow an array to be declared without a constant value. The professor of the class I'm writing this code for was not clear on whether or not we could use malloc() for this assignment. Assuming I cannot using `malloc()`, is there any way I can create the array `histPlot[][]` to have a height of exactly `max + 1`?

EDIT: So I've accepted that there is no real way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without using `malloc()` or some similar function. I did manage to find a solution that doesn't involve those functions or a 2D array at all, but thank you to those who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C99, fundamentally, if it's a variable length array, you need dynamic allocation. This means `malloc` or one of the similar functions.

If you use C99 you can just declare it directly.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is C99 but it still wouldn't let me declare it directly. I did, however, find a different solution to my problem that circumvents the need for malloc() or a 2D array at all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some systems provide an [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) function. (However, this is not standard C.)

Outside of that, there's no real way to get a dynamically sized array.

I can offer the following more or less silly workarounds:

- use `calloc` or `realloc` to allocate memory (following the letter of the rule that you can't use `malloc` but not the spirit)
- ... or `mmap` (if your platform has that)
- if it doesn't have to be a real array, use a [temporary file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) to store your data (access via `fseek`, `fread`, `fwrite`)
- if you can use a linked list instead, you can build one of those on the stack by recursive function calls

Comment: Haha, I did get a good chuckled with that first solution of yours. I should have been more clear, the only libraries we can use are stdio.h math.h and ctype.h. Fortunately I managed to come up with a completely different solution that works and bypasses the need for a 2D array at all. Thank you very much for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

In C99, you are allowed to declare variable length arrays using values that are not available until runtime. However, you can't used a fixed initializer. What that means is that instead of

```
char histPlot[max+1][52] = "";
```

you would have to write something like this:

```
char histPlot[max+1][52];
for (int i=0; i<=max; i++) {
    strcpy(histPlot[i], "");
}
```

Notice that the ability to declare an int inside a `for()` statement is another C99 extension. To compile this code successfully, you will probably have to add something like `-std=c99` to the command line.

I should also point out that there is much more space available on the heap than on the stack. If you need to declare a large array (i.e., if the value of `max` is more than a few hundred), then it would make sense to use `malloc()` to create an array on the heap.

Comment: My issue was that I couldn't even declare the array without using constant values. Luckily, I found a different solution to my problem that bypasses the need for a 2D array entirely. I did not know the bit about the heap and stack, so thank you for teaching me something new in C!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in a function on the stack like this if it is not too big.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void a(int b,int c) {
    char d[b][c];
    d[0][1] = 'a';
    printf("%c\n",d[0][1]);
    return;
}
int main() {
    a(8,14);
    return 1;
}
```

Output: a